# I2C Programm stops running after a few seconds / Remote I/O Error nr 121

Tags: i2c, remote

i have an Arduino Mega hooked as slave to the raspi via i2c.

My python scripts looks like this

```
import smbus
import time


bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x08

def requestreading():
    block = bus.read_i2c_block_data((SLAVE_ADDRESS), 0, 8)

    print(block)


while True:
    #var = input("Press any key for reading: ")
    requestreading()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    #n = input("Please enter 's':")
    #if n.strip() == 's':
        #break
```

The code runs for a short time and prints out the values in the shell but then gives me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      requestreading()
block = bus.read_i2c_block_data((SLAVE_ADDRESS), 0, 8)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

This is the slave code on the Arduino Mega:

```
#include <Wire.h>

int SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x08;
int analogPin1 = A0;
int analogPin2 = A1;
int analogPin3 = A2;
int analogPin4 = A3;


void setup(){
  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  Wire.onRequest(sendAnalogReading);
}

void loop(){


}

void sendAnalogReading(){

  uint16_t reading1 = analogRead(analogPin1);
  uint16_t reading2 = analogRead(analogPin2);
  uint16_t reading3 = analogRead(analogPin3);
  uint16_t reading4 = analogRead(analogPin4);


Wire.write((char *) &reading1, 2);
Wire.write((char *) &reading2, 2);
Wire.write((char *) &reading3, 2);
Wire.write((char *) &reading4, 2);

}
```

can anybody tell me the reason for this error?

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Does `i2cdetect -y 1` find your Arduino after you script crashes? Also, try slowing the loop down with a short delay.

Comment: Is that your actual code - seems like the formatting is missing?

Comment: @RogerJones yes it continuously finds the Arduino via i2cdetect. i added a time.sleep(1) in the loop but it still crashes after around 35 readings. any other ideas?

Comment: @CoderMike yes this is the complete python script

Comment: Could you add the actual script with cut&paste. The given script is invalid and incorrectly formatted.

Comment: Your missing spacing in your function and while loop and i'm pretty sure you can't have spaces in function names.

Comment: How about `while i2cdump -y -r 0-7 1 0x08 c; do sleep 1; done`? I think that's the right invocation to replicate your Python code.

Comment: @CoderMike now used copy&paste. typed it up the first time thus mistake

Comment: @joan here you go, any suggestions?

Comment: @RogerJones you mean i put that command into my terminal or in the python script? i put it in the terminal and then ran the program it still gave the same error message as it crashed. Other suggestions or did i do something wrong?

Comment: @RogerJones i added a screenshot to the original question of the terminal output . maybe this provides more insights

Comment: There's a `1` missing between `0-7` and `0x08`.

Comment: @RogerJones the picture in the question. program still gives the same error after a few seconds. can you make sense of the response or dou have any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the slave code too. The slave might be expecting something else on the end of read. So subsequent read is not the actual code that slave expects so it sends error back to the master.

Comment: @Bungee75 i have edited the question. i am using an Arduino Mega. The program runs for a period of time before it crashes. i guess its a problem on the i2c bus that there are simultaneous actions that shouldn't occur??

Comment: i am not using a level shifter between the Raspi and the arduino Mega. Might this be the problem of why it cuts out?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using a level converter before. I now integrated it for the SCL and SDA line and the program runs a lot more stable even for shorter sleep times. However it still crashes eventually which i figure is due to a voltage that is between 1.1V and 2.4V und thus is neither defined as high or low and the program therefore shuts down.

is there a way to filter values that are in between?

Comment: That's what the pull-up resistors on SCL and SDA are for: to drive the voltage up to 3.3v when the lines are "idle". The Pi or Arduino clamp them to ground when they want to send data. What level converter are you using and where are you seeing 2.4v?

Comment: @RogerJones i am using a TXS0108E Texas Instruments. i am not seeing the 2.4V. it's just that i'm guessing that there is value thats neither high or low and the raspberry therefore can't interpret it and goes to error mode and returns I/O Error. the level converter has improved the stability quite a bit but not indefinitely.

Comment: The level converter should be driving the signals high and low without a problem. Are you using extra pull-up resistors on either side of the level converter chip? From a quick look at the datasheet that might be a problem as they can reduce the effect of the ones built into the chip. Give the "Remote IO Error" you are seeing (suggesting that the Arduino is not sending an ACK back) and that the level converter helped my next suggestion would be to to check your connections and try and inspect the I2C signals with an oscilloscope as the problem seems to be an electrical one.

Comment: @RogerJones no i am not using extra pullup resistors, as both the mega and the Arduino have built in ones. I am however connecting the OE pin on the converter via 10kO to ground as suggested in the data sheet from the level converter. i looked with an oscilloscope but couldn't identify a possible problem.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.